# Xamarin.IOS webservice error on mobile data

Tags: web-services, xamarin.ios, socketexception

If I use an Domain Name is works fine, but a I need use the ip address and not working. On WIFI the app also works as expected. The problem is with mobile data and the ip address.

I'm running app in IOS 10.3.1 and T-Mobile.

Here are the StackTrace of the error:

Instance {System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network is unreachable
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in :0 
at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00000] in :0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in :0 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 } System.Net.WebException

Comment: Are you using a public IP address? Try accessing the address from outside the app, the browser by example.

Comment: Outside the app is working fine. Yes, the IP Address is public.